# "Chrome Apps" webview.executeScript access guest global varibles

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I can access a Chrome App Webview HTML with:

```
webview.executeScript(
    {code: 'document.documentElement.innerHTML'},
    function(results) {
      // results[0] would have the webview's innerHTML.
    });
```

But I would like to get the value of global variables in the Guest like so:

```
webview.executeScript(
   {code: 'window.globalVar'},
   function(results) {
   // results[0] should have the webview's value of "globalVar".
   });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script

Comment: Thanks Xan, there is a lot of content on the link you suggest. It is difficult to figure out if it applies to current "Chrome App Webviews". It appears that I could be missing configuration in the manifest.json, but from there, I am still lost. The other post is for Chrome Extensions, I am not sure how much applies to Chrome Apps, that will be running in Cordova.

Comment: The point is, `window` objects of the page and the content script are isolated. It does not matter whether it's a webview. But you can access the "real" `window` by injecting a page-level script.

Comment: Just to be clear, the challenge I am having is getting data BACK from the Guest. I can inject a script and have it interact with the data on the Guest, but using a simple "return window.globalVar" is not sending the data back to the host. I am wondering if I should be using "message passing" instead?

Comment: Right.. Let me find a question for that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26740141/934239

Answer (score 4):

An answer to summarize the steps required.

1) You inject a content script with `webview.executeScript()` into the embedded page.

2) Since the page's real `window` is isolated, you need a page-level script to access it. You inject it with a `<script>` tag as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).

3) The page-level script can access the `window` object, but cannot talk to the app script. However, it can fire a custom DOM event, that the content script can catch. Discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26740141/934239).

4) Finally, from the content script you need to send a message to your app script. <del>The content script calls `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, while the app script listens with `chrome.runtime.onMessage`.</del> `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` does not seem to be available to webview content scripts injected with `webview.executeScript()`. A workaround is to use `postMessage` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30367455/934239).

It's a bit of an onion structure, that's why you need 2 steps "in" and 2 steps "out". You can't really do it in the return value that's passed to the `executeScript` callback, since at least one of the "out" steps will be asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and complete answer, I will give that a try ;) FYI, I a trying to get Latitude and Longitude from a BING Map to display on a Google Map.

Comment: Please do; I'm not 100% sure of the answer since I have little to no experience with apps. But that's how `executeScript` works in extensions.

Comment: I am not sure how common this tool is, but I am using Chrome Dev Editor (Developer Preview) to play with Cordova Chrome Apps, and it is fantastic. Very quick and easy to mock up a simple test.

Comment: Success! I think I found the simple shortcut to getting data from the Guest. Inject a Script Tag that writes the data to the Guest Console, then use this: webview.addEventListener('consolemessage', function(e) {
  console.log('Guest page logged a message: ', e.message);
});

Comment: I don't think it's a very good shortcut, since the page in question can also print to the console. A custom event is less likely to interfere.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject a script that inserts a DOM node with the global variable's value. Then you return that node's innerHTML and you have your value right away without using a callback:

```
var code = "script = document.createElement('script'); script.text=\"var n=document.createElement('span');n.style.display='none';n.id='my-id';n.innerHTML=window.globalVar;document.body.appendChild(n)\"; document.head.appendChild(script);document.getElementById('my-id').innerHTML"

webview.executeScript(
    {code: code},
    function(results) {
      console.log(results[0]);
    });
```

Just use an ID for the DOM node that is not used and you should be fine. It works for me.

Comment: @fareednamrouti Thanks. It was just an idea that occurred to me :)

Comment: actually this is security issue and considered as hack LOL